# CSS Div Position Behaviour

Tags: css, css-position, fixed, absolute

I have issues with understanding the div position (relative, absolute, fixed) properties. I basically have an absolute div centered. Inside the div it should be possible to scroll vertically and horizontally. Inside this div should be a fixed header with a width larger than to screen (overflow) and a content div which has an overflow vertically and horizontally as well.

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px auto;
    position: fixed;
}

.container {
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    height: calc(100% - 20px);
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    background: #2924aa;
    overflow: scroll;
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 20;
}

.container-header {
    width: calc(100%);
    height: calc(10%);
    background: #2924aa;
    overflow: visible;
    z-index: 10;
    position: fixed;
    background: red;
}

.container-body {
    width: calc(110%);
    height: calc(110%);
    background: #2924aa;
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    background: green;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
      
    <div class="container-header"></div>
      
    <div class="container-body"></div>
      
  </div>
```

Here is my plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/wCWvHPcuYmVMql5HulHy

Comment: Your main container should have `position: relative;` otherwise `.continer-body` is calculated relative to your browser screen. Fixed is always calculated within regards to the screen.

Answer (score 1):

So i think the main question you have is in regards to the Position Attribute in CSS3. Below is a brief summary of each possible value.

**CSS Positioning**
The CSS positioning attribute of position has four different values.
*Static* - Static is the default value for position. It keeps the element on the page in its place, and it scrolls up the page as you scroll.
*Relative* - Relative positioning is pretty much as the same as static; however, you can use the *left*, *right*, *top*, and *bottom* attributes to alter the placement of the element *relative* to its original position.
*Fixed* - A fixed element's position is in relation to the viewport (i.e. the browser) therefore, an element with a fixed position does not scroll with the page, because when you scroll the viewport does not change. However, if you resize the browser, the element will change position.
*Absolute* - A element with an absolute position, is positioned relative to its parent element (i.e. the element that contains it).

A good resource for more information, including some diagrams can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp).